# Display file input only when previous file input is not empty

Tags: html, css, file, input

How can I get the last input field to display after the 3rd is clicked, as I can only get 3 inputs to display?

My ideas is to have the following input display only after the previous has been fulfilled, but I'm stuck at this last input.

I require that only the 1st input be required, as only 1 image is required on my website, but the user can upload more.

But this code requires the inputs to be validated via required.

Any ideas of another method?

```css
input {
  display: block
}

#csvfile {
  display: none
}

#filename2 {
  display: none
}

#csvfile2 {
  display: none
}

#filename:valid+#csvfile {
  display: block
}

#csvfile:valid+#filename2 {
  display: block
}

#filename2:valid+#cvsfile2 {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filename" required name="filename" />
<input type="file" id="csvfile" required name="csvfile" />
<input type="file" id="filename2" required name="filename2" />
<input type="file" id="csvfile2" name="csvfile2" />
```

Comment: You simply have a typo. `#filename2:valid+#cvsfile2` should be `#filename2:valid+#csvfile2`. The `v` and `s` are the wrong way around. Correcting this will fix your problem.

Comment: ok thank you, Any idea how to do this without the inputs being REQUIRED i only need the 1st input to be required.. thank you all the same.

Comment: Im still only getting 3 inputs , i have 4 that i wish to be synchronous...But thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want all of the file inputs to be required, you won't be able to reliably detect whether or not they are empty with css only (the :valid pseudo-class you are using will only work for required fields). You will need some JavaScript to detect whether or not each file input contains a file. Following is an example:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');

for (let elem of elems) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    let target = event.target;
    let next = target.nextElementSibling;
    if (target.files.length) {
      next.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      next.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="filename" type="file" name="filename" required />
<input class="hidden" id="csvfile" type="file" name="csvfile" />
<input class="hidden" id="filename2" type="file" name="filename2" />
<input class="hidden" id="csvfile2" type="file" name="csvfile2" />
```